# Confusion about O(logn)

Tags: big-o

When we say something runs in O(logn), we mean that its running time is bounded by f(n) where f(n) <= clogn for n >= n0 for some n0 and constant c, where n0 >= 0. However, this implies logn is defined on 0 right? So what is log0 in the context of big O?

Comment: The law is defined only when `n` is big enough, so it makes no sense to speak about little value of `n`.

Comment: I'm having a hard time finding anything about the >= 0 part. Where did you see this?

Comment: > However, this implies logn is defined on 0 right?

No, it doesn't.

Comment: *n0* must not be negative, that is true. But that does not mean it has to be zero. You need to be able to find ONE such *n0* so that the inequality holds. You can pick it yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: So do we just continue to say logn is undefined on 0?

Comment: @AbhishekManikandan Yes. We have not redefined the logarithm; life goes on as before.

Answer (score -1):

'n' refers to input length

if n = 0, it implies that there is no input

hence, n0 >= 1

[image: Big-Oh]